# How could I schedule an API call that users sign up for?

Tags: python, rest, api, automation, cron

I have a REST API service that I want to call on at scheduled times. Currently, I call the API using a basic cronjob on a server every day at 8:00am.

I want to scale up and allow my users to schedule a time they would like to receive the notification from my API call. How could I go about doing this? I know I would need to keep a database of user requests and their associated times, however I am not sure if continuing to use cron is the best way about this... (I would prefer not to use third party services in order to keep costs down)

I am having trouble wrapping my head this, if anybody has any advice that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If the time frame is going to be something simple, like one-per-day, once-per-week, etc., using the cron.d folder is a fairly trivial and in my opinion appropriate solution.

The simplest way would be each user having their own file with a simple one-line cron statement that reflects their selected time. When the user selects their time, part of your service creates the correct file for that user. You can go on from there.

Whether or not you put them in a database is really a question of your own system design; given a proper file naming scheme, you could feasibly do this without having to keep that requested time in persistent storage.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will look into it!